# Google Sheets different font sizes in same call

Tags: font-size

I'm working on a script to custom build a report in Google Sheets. I have a header made from a range of cells that are merged and I need to get some of the text set at 24 point font and some at 18 point within the merged range. I have no clue how to start doing this. Here is my code so far. The next step will be to set the '(Frequency Range from 80M to 1G)' to 18 point font.

```
function radImmunity() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.insertSheet('Radiated Immunity');  //Create Rad Imm sheet
    var radImm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      radImm.getRange('A1:J4').merge();
      radImm.getRange('A1:J4').setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
      radImm.getRange('A1').setValue('Radiated Immunity Test                                                             (Frequency Range from 80M to 1G)')
      radImm.getRange('A1').setHorizontalAlignment("center").setVerticalAlignment("top").setFontSize(24).setFontWeight("bold");
      radImm.getRange('A1:J4').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you need is:

```js
radImm.getRange('A1:J4').setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText('Radiated Immunity Test\n(Frequency Range from 80M to 1G)').setTextStyle(0, 23, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).build()).setTextStyle(23, 55, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(18).build()).build());
```

I would break that into pieces, though, so it looks like this:

```js
var fontStyle24 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build()
var fontStyle18 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(18).setBold(true).build()
var titleRichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
.setText('Radiated Immunity Test\n(Frequency Range from 80M to 1G)')
.setTextStyle( 0, 23, fontStyle24)
.setTextStyle(23, 55, fontStyle18)
.build();

radImm.getRange('A1').setRichTextValue(titleRichText)
```

The key here is `setRichTextValue()` lets you pick pieces of the string to format. Note that I also replace the multiple spaces with a line break. You don't have to do this, of course, but it's more robust than counting on word wrap.

---

If I was going to refactor your whole code snippet, though, it'd end up looking like this:

```js
function radImmunity() {

  // Create the font styles we'll use later
  var fontStyle24 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build()
  var fontStyle18 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(18).setBold(true).build()
  var titleRichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('Radiated Immunity Test\n(Frequency Range from 80M to 1G)')
  .setTextStyle( 0, 23, fontStyle24)
  .setTextStyle(23, 55, fontStyle18)
  .build();

  // Insert a new sheet  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var radImm = sheet.insertSheet('Radiated Immunity');  //Create Rad Imm sheet

  // Add and format the title
  var titleRange = radImm.getRange('A1:J4')
  titleRange.merge();
  titleRange.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
  titleRange.setHorizontalAlignment("center").setVerticalAlignment("top")
  titleRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
  titleRange.setRichTextValue(titleRichText)

}
```

The only significant suggestion I have here is to not call `getRange()` over and over.

---

Note to future readers: I found this answer using the new(ish) tool to record macros.
[image: RecordMacroMenu]